# Implementing a XML Flash site with a Joomla Website? 

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, joomla

You have all seen sites, that have content that loads and displays with various effects without a page refresh.  The are wonderful. Such sites as pandora.com, groveshark.com  and hypem.com come to my mind when looking for examples of sites with music player/video play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simply not going to be an easy way to convert a Joomla! installation into a backend for an XML-driven Flash site.